# What am I missing in this Authenticaton implementation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, basic-authentication

This is a Rails app and I have implemented authentiction on a controller with the exception of 1 view like this

```
 before_filter :authenticate, except: [:new]
```

authentication is working great within the controller.

allows public view of.............

```
localhost:3000/softruns/new
```

and does **NOT** allow public view of.............

```
localhost:3000/softrunss/1/edit
localhost:3000/softruns  <---- index page
```

The problem is that when the form that is in localhost:3000/softruns/new is submitted by user, it then triggers the authentication.
I have even redirected the user to home/index.html page upon successful submission.

what may I be missing ?
here is my softruns_controller.rb

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class SoftrunsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate, except: [:new]  
  before_action :set_softrun, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /softruns
  # GET /softruns.json
  def index
    @softruns = Softrun.all
  end

  # GET /softruns/1
  # GET /softruns/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /softruns/new
  def new
    @softrun = Softrun.new
  end

  # GET /softruns/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /softruns
  # POST /softruns.json
  def create
    @softrun = Softrun.new(softrun_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @softrun.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Softrun was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @softrun }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @softrun.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /softruns/1
  # PATCH/PUT /softruns/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @softrun.update(softrun_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @softrun, notice: 'Softrun was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @softrun.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /softruns/1
  # DELETE /softruns/1.json
  def destroy
    @softrun.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to softruns_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_softrun
      @softrun = Softrun.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def softrun_params
      params.require(:softrun).permit(:soft_email, :soft_twitter, :prim_session)
    end
  private 
    def authenticate 
      userhash = { } 
      User.all.each do |user|
        userhash.store(user.username, user.password) 
      end

      authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest("localhost") do |username| 
      userhash[username] 
      end 
    end 
end
```

Comment: `authenticate`... seems odd to me. You're doing a certain action with **all users** when **any user** takes **any action that requires authentication**. Why? What's the idea behind this?

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits the form it will call action create and that one requires authentication, it fails because of that. If you add this one on the list of exceptions you will be able to create new record as you wish.

```
before_filter :authenticate, except: [:new, :create]
```

More, before_action and before_filter are the same (Rails 4 prefers first)
In Rails you don't have to use private on each private method. everything within the class that is below the private will be private